# Set closure in $L_2[−1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose we have set M in the space $L_2[-1, 1]$ with norm $||x|| = (\int_{-1}^{1} |x(t)|^2 dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, where M:
$$ M = \{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]: p(0) = 0\}$$
It's easy to check, that $Lin(M) = M$. How to prove that $\overline{Lin(M)} = L_2[-1, 1]$?

I had the following idea. Let's fix $\epsilon > 0$, then for every fixed $\epsilon$ consider continuous functions $g(x)$ such that for that $\epsilon$ $\quad g(x) = 0, x \in [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$. I want to prove that for every function $g(x)$ there exist a polynomial $p(x) \in M$ sucth that: $$
\rho(g, p) = ||g(x) - p(x)|| = (\int_{-1}^{1} |g(t)-p(t)|^2 dt)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \epsilon
$$

Then after that I can write the following estimates and prove the initial statement: $$\forall f \in L_2[-1, 1] \quad\exists p\in M:
\rho(f, p) \leq\rho(f, g)+\rho(g, p) < 2\epsilon
$$

But it is not clear how to prove the existence of a polynomial $p(x) \in M$ for the functions $g(x)$ described above. First of all, I thought about the Weierstrass theorem, but the problem arises in the fact that in that theorem the polynomial is arbitrary and does not necessarily have a zero free coefficient. There was also an idea to construct this polynomial explicitly using the formula for the metric $\rho(g, p)$ and saying that the inequality $\rho(g, p) < \epsilon$ holds for any $\epsilon$, but no good came of it. How to prove statement above?

Comment: By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, $M$ is dense (using uniform norm)  in the space of continuous functions $\mathcal{C}[-1,1]$ that vanishes at 0. The constant function $1$ can be a proximate in $L_2$ by continuous function that vanish vanish at one: $f_n=1-\mathbb{1}_{[-2^{-n},2^{-n}]}$; this can be uniformly approximated by polynomials in $M$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz The Weierstrass theorem suffices. If $p_n\to f$ and $f(0)=0$ then $p_n(0)\to 0,$ hence $p_n-p_n(0)\to f.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: I know, It is just that my Swiss army knife is equipped with the Stone-Weierstrass theorem and use it all the time.

Comment: @kontsev_: now that $1$ is part of the set of functions you can approximate in $L_2$, know the whole this is trivial since the set of polynomials, which include the constant function $1$ is dense in $L_2$

Comment: @OliverDíaz: I got 2 questions. First, you proved that $f_n$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials in M, but this true in $C[-1, 1]$, why does this tru in $L_2[-1, 1]$? Second, you proved that 1 can be proximated by $p \in M$ and said that set of polynomials which contains 1 is dense $L_2$, but how this proves that $Cl(M) = L_2$? Is there any lemma?

Comment: @kontsev_: $\|f\|_2\leq2\|f\|_\infty$ so if $\|\phi-\phi_n\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, then $\|\phi=\phi_n\|_2$ converges to $0$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I understood, thanks! But what about my second question above?

Comment: @kontsev_: It is a well known fact that step functions and/or continuous functions are dense in any $L_p$. If you prefer to work with step functions, that is fine. Try to approximate the indicator function of $(a, b)$ by a continuous function for example.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I mean, if we proved that 1 can be proximate by polynomials from M why does it follow that every set of polynomials which contains 1 can be proximate by polynomials from M?

Comment: @OliverDíaz I checked up my Swiss army knife: tools of Euler and Bernoulli brothers are available, but not Stone-Weierstrass. Are you sure your device is Swiss made ? :-)

Comment: Actually is a Made In AMERICA! tool (not Swiss). Stone is American, and hence my tendency to add him to the Weierstrass theorem. A little too patriotic on my side... not really, actually I picked that mania from Klaus Bichteler (a German mathematician how emigrated to America and who taught me many things in Mathematics)